# NextJS > Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I'm trying to wrap a card component using the Link component from 'next/link'. When I click the card it should have taken me to the link but it's not doing that. instead, I'm getting a warning ' Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail'.
How can I fix this?

here's the code:

```
<div className="flex justify_between align_center flex_wrap mb_2 ">
    {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].map((item) => (
      <Link href="/blog-details" key={item}>
        <BlogCard />
      </Link>
    ))}
```

Comment: have you tried adding `passHref` prop to `Link` component ?

Comment: yes, dosent work

Comment: What does your `BlogCard` component look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is actually stated in the official documentation. You probably need to check out all the cases to see which case you are fall in. It highly depends on your `<BlogCard />` structure. Then you can `forward` the `href` and `ref` to your custom component.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-functional-component